# Using .NET to create a Base 64 byte array replicating Java code

Tags: java, c#, .net-core, encryption

For a project at work, I need to convert a string into a byte array which can then be fed into and AES/CBC/PKCS5 decryption algorithm.  In this case I need to take existing Java code which does the work, and turn it into .NET Core code.

The first step taken in the Java code is this line:

`byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode( Utils.getBytes(masterKey) );`

From what I've found when Googling, this line in C# should replicate the functionality.

`var masterKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(masterKey);`

And they do return very similar byte arrays.

The first 10 bytes of the c# generated array are:  `68 163 160 50 213 109 12 103`

The first 10 bytes of the Java generated array are: `68 -93 -96 50 -43 109 12 103`

So they're very similar, but where the Java array has negative numbers, the c# array has the same value, but with 256 added to it.

Are these differences enough to throw off the later decryption code (AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding Cipher in Java, and AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding AESManaged in .NET Core)  The ultimate issue I'm having is that the Java code returns the decrypted value, my .NET Core code returns garbage.  So I went through the code line by line to try and find differences in output, and this was the first one I hit.

I have no control over the Java code, and cannot edit it, so any solution should be on the .NET Core side only.  If that's impossible, I need to start a whole process with our internet security people to get that code changed and that's a headache I'm not looking forward to.

Comment: Java simply doesn't have unsigned bytes, and so you're see the equivalent 8-bit signed numbers. This is unlikely to be the cause of your issues.

Comment: That's just the difference of signed vs. unsigned values. They're the same values, they're just displayed differently (since Java doesn't have unsigned values). The data is the same, so everything's fine so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes in C# are unsigned by default, since they tend to represent raw binary data, not actual numbers. If you want to treat bytes as signed numbers, there's the `sbyte` type.

In Java, signed is the default for all numbers and there's no unsigned alternative, for reasons that are unknown to me (if you have a reliable source, feel free to comment).

You can verify that your values in C# are the same as in Java by casting the `byte` array to an `sbyte` array:

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 68, 163, 160, 50, 213, 109, 12, 103 };
foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine((sbyte) b);
}
```

Prints:

```
68
-93
-96
50
-43
109
12
103
```

which is the same as your values from Java.

If your interested in how the same 8 bits are interpreted as unsigned or signed values, read about  [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

Thus, this is not the cause of your program being incorrect. Carry on debugging, and feel free to ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: And they're the same in hex!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to the original post, this is expected behavior and should not be the cause of my larger issue.  I will make another post describing the larger issue I'm having with the decryption.  Thank you to those that commented.